# Iterating Django template variables in javascript, access by a changing index

Tags: javascript, python, django

How would it be possible to access or iterate a django list within javascript using a changing INDEX.

For example:

```
<script>
    for (var i=0; i < "{{ django_list|length }}".toInt(); i++) {
         var e = "{{ django_list" + i.toString() + " }}"; // this gives an error
         ...    //  it does not parse a chunked ^ template variable properly
         ...
    }
</script>
```

Some background. This is  a pure .js file that is being rendered by django. That part works, it just does not interpret a substringed out django template var syntax.

I'd prefer a solution which avoids encoding into JSON or anything similar. Template form is preferred because I need the methods of the variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Can u not use a for each loop?

Comment: Not for this example, JS is controlling the iteration

Answer (score 1):

As always, [encode as JSON](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/201/).

```
{% load jsonify %}

var data = {{ django_list|jsonify }};

for (...) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's what my code looks like currently, but is there any way which avoids encoding? I need the models METHODS in the template, and encoding into JSON means everything aside from fields are lost. Thanks

Comment: You can't access the Django code from JavaScript without performing a XHR. If you don't actually need the code then create a list or dict from the data you do need and encode that.

Comment: You can call methods, which is good enough. {{ some_model.some_function }}. And encoding the model into JSON makes it so we lose this functionality.

Comment: "then create a list or dict from the data you do need and encode that" So you mean for every model call the method needed, create a list and pass it into the template? Can you be more clear on the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a for each loop?

```
{%  for item in django_list  %}
//Whatever you wish to do with item goes here
{% endfor %}
```

For more see the link
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty

Comment: I just wanted to see if doing what was above in the example was possible. Good suggestion though

Comment: There are situations where we need the index. What if it was a big JS file with a global index which is changing dynamically. We can' just have a for loop in the JS, we need to use the index to access the list.

Comment: I do not understand you. As I said within the for loop you can always have the forloop.counter using which u can manipulate your items.
Am I not getting something?

Comment: If you just had a for loop with the django {% %} syntax, it would iterate all at once when the loop is hit, independent of the outside JS. That's not the intended goal though. What if the index incrementing was based off of other factors? Like jQuery click event handlers.

Comment: I think that is possible using the dot operator.
Ill check and post an edit.

Comment: Yes, the dot operator {{ some_list.4 }} would get you the 5th element. But how can we specify the number in the dot with a JS variable? As in the example presented "{{ some_list" + some_num + " }}" won't work. Thanks.

Comment: Guess you are right you could always build your own template tag if your requirements are so particular.